# What is the correct way to use char *array[] string arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm writing a program that takes a line of input, and parses the line of input like command line arguments would be parsed by a regular command line program. I'm using a variable called char *args[] to contain the parsed strings of input, the parsing and the variable very much like a regular command line program would with char *argv[]. I was working with this program and found that even though I loop through the arguments, adding each one to char *args[], the end result is that the variable char *args[] only contains the last "argument" to be stored in that array.

Here's the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char input[200];
  printf(">");
  gets(input);
  int i=0;
  int t=0;
  int l=0;
  bool space=false;
  char arr[50];
  char *str;
  char *args[10];
  memset(&arr,0,sizeof(arr));
  memset(&str,0,sizeof(str));
  memset(&args,0,sizeof(args));
  for(i;i<sizeof(input);i++)
  {
    printf("l=%d,t=%d\n",l,t);
    if(input[i]=='\0')
      break;
    if(input[i]==' ')
    {
      if(!space)
      {
        printf("arr : %s...\n",arr);
        str=arr;
        printf("str : %s...\n",str);
        args[l]=str;
        printf("args[%d] : %s...\n",l,args[l]);
        memset(&arr,0,sizeof(arr));
        memset(&str,0,sizeof(str));
        t=0;
        l++;
        space=true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      arr[t]=input[i];
      space=false;
      t++;
    }
  }
  printf("arr : %s...\n",arr);
  str=arr;
  printf("str : %s...\n",str);
  args[l]=str;
  printf("args[%d] : %s...\n",l,args[l]);

  printf("\n");

  //Shows that all of char *args[] is the last string to be set...
  int j=0;
  for(j;j<=l;j++)
  {
    printf("args[%d] = %s...\n",j,args[j]);
  }
  //hello and goodbye are set and output below like a normal char *args[]
  //array should...
  args[0] = "hello";
  args[1] = "goodbye";
  j=0;
  for(j;j<=l;j++)
  {
    printf("args[%d] = %s...\n",j,args[j]);
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Here is some sample output...

```
C:\Users\Auguest\Desktop>basecalc.exe
>asdf hsdf ewrr ewr
l=0,t=0
l=0,t=1
l=0,t=2
l=0,t=3
l=0,t=4
arr : asdf...
str : asdf...
args[0] : asdf...
l=1,t=0
l=1,t=1
l=1,t=2
l=1,t=3
l=1,t=4
arr : hsdf...
str : hsdf...
args[1] : hsdf...
l=2,t=0
l=2,t=1
l=2,t=2
l=2,t=3
l=2,t=4
arr : ewrr...
str : ewrr...
args[2] : ewrr...
l=3,t=0
l=3,t=1
l=3,t=2
l=3,t=3
arr : ewr...
str : ewr...
args[3] : ewr...

args[0] = ewr...
args[1] = ewr...
args[2] = ewr...
args[3] = ewr...
args[0] = hello...
args[1] = goodbye...
args[2] = ewr...
args[3] = ewr...

C:\Users\August\Desktop>
```

I am using MinGW gcc 4.9.3 on Windows XP...

I have a feeling that I am not using char *args[] correctly. What is the correct way to loop through this array and assign each entry a value? What is the correct way to use char *args[] in general? If it is something else with my program please say so, I'm sure the internet would like to hear.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just a real mess, and is going to take a lot more TLC than a quick answer.  I would suggest reading up on C pointers, strings, and memory allocation.  Also, sizeof() is a static, compile-time operator, and will always return 200 in your case.  I think you meant to use strlen().

Comment: Minor comment: variable names like `l` aren't great because it looks remarkably similar to `1` in many fonts.

Comment: You might also want to use something like `strtok()` to parse the string instead of hand rolling your own in your look.

Comment: The elements of `args[]` are always set to `str` which is only ever assigned `arr`.  So every element of `args[]` will be pointing to the same string (that gets changed repeatedly).  Try using `args[l] = strdup(str);`

Comment: @MichaelBurr Your comment would make a good answer.  I'd recommend posting that.

Comment: Don't `typedef` or `#define` `bool` and the constants! Use the standard type and `stdbool.h`. Also `gets` has been removed from the standard library intentionally. **Never ever** use it.

Comment: Yeah I know its unsafe when coupled with fixed-dimension arrays; buffer overflows to the max. Also for anyone reading sgets is safe, and strcat and that family of functions are also unsafe, use instead strncat and that family of functions. I'm fine with the code right now because I may want to write my own exploit for my own program for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one array (arr[]) to hold a copy of the string you are currently processing - and when you hit a space, you set your next pointer in args[l] to point to the current contents of arr[].  The next time through your loop though, you replace the contents of arr[] with the next string, and since args[0] up to args[l-1] all point to that single copy of arr[], they all end displaying only the last contents you copied into arr[].

There are many more elegant ways of doing what you want.... but maybe the easiest for you to try first (based on looking at the code you have already written) is to make 'arr[]' into a two-dimensional array, from your hardcoded constants, you could use 'arr[10][50]', and when filling in arr[][], use 'arr[l][t] = input[i];'.  And when assigning args[l], use 'args[l] = &(arr[l][0]);'.

Once you start to understand how pointers, arrays, etc work more, you can then start simplifying your code, making it safer (avoiding buffer overflows, for example), reducing unnecessary copies (i.e. can you just set args[l] to point to the beginning of each string inside the 'input[]' array directly, rather than copying that to a separate array first?), and so on.

Hope this helps you get onto the right track.....

Comment: Many thanks! I never realized the use of pointers could help to avoid  buffer overflows. I do know that gets() is unsafe, especially with the fixed-dimension arrays receiving their input, but I'm the only one using the program so I guess I'm the only one whose gonna hack it. ;) p.s. Could you lead me in the right direction for further reading on how pointers can help avoid buffer overflows? Thank you once again!

Comment: I was implying that your input buffer is of size 200, but your arr[] array is only of size 50, so if one of the strings in the input[] array is larger than 50 bytes, you'll overflow the arr[] array.  One option to avoid that would be to replace the ' ' characters in the input[] array with the NULL terminator character ('\0'), and then just have args[l] point to the start of each string within the input[] array itself.  That avoids one of your potential buffer overflows in your code.....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Within this block...

```
  if(!space)
  {
    printf("arr : %s...\n",arr);
    str=arr;
    printf("str : %s...\n",str);
    args[l]=str;
    printf("args[%d] : %s...\n",l,args[l]);
    memset(&arr,0,sizeof(arr));
    memset(&str,0,sizeof(str));
    t=0;
    l++;
    space=true;
  }
```

Each entry in args[] is set to the pointer str, so all of the entries in the args[] array are set to the same pointer, str, which points to the latest state of the arr variable...

Instead of using char *args[] char args[][] should be used. Note : dimensions of the args[][] two-dimensional array are required at compile time.

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);

Should be used to set each args[x] entry to the current state of the arr variable.

Comment: You may want to double-check the `memset(&arr,0,sizeof(arr));` syntax. If `arr` and `str` are already arrays (and thus *pointers*), your syntax is incorrect and should be generating warnings.